# overflow-x refusing to show?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am working on a site and I cant manage to get the overflow-x to scroll when the window is shrunk down (emulating a tablet/mobile).

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Is all I can think of that would be controlling this. You can view the site [HERE](http://www.beachhousevictoria.com/).

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can force scroll by setting overflow: scroll;

Comment: You have overflow set to hidden on the body, you also shouldn't need to set the overflow on the `html` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a min-width set on your `#wrapper` div, which technically means it will never have any overflowing content.

Set the CSS for the wrapper to the following:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 2560px;
    min-width: 900px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And remove the overflow properties from the CSS for the `body` & `html` elements, they are both unnecessary.

After making the above changes you should be able to scroll horizontally on mobile devices, the min-width value above will likely need changing though.

Comment: Sean I did try all of this previously with no luck, not sure why its not cooperating. I have applied these changes live on the site now, but something is still causing it to not want to scroll.

Comment: Hi Matt. The site appears to be scrolling fine for me now - are you testing this on a mobile/other kind of device (I'm on a PC atm)?

Comment: Im testing on a iPad, on my computer I see scrolls for each section, I also applied the changes that HeXa made below. What is happening on the iPad is its only showing about 3/4 of the page then the rest is cut off, maybe I should be adjusting the zoom or setting a media query for the page to load properly on a mobile/ipad?!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iPad or I could test it too ... but yes if this doesn't work then media queries would be my recommendation. You're website would be easy to scale with them as it seems to have a column type layout, simple reduce the number of columns for the iPad or make them slimmer.

Comment: There are numerous resources out there if you need help with media queries, just have a Google and see what you find :)

Comment: Yeah I have used media queries in the past, I was hoping to just have a fixed style site, but dont think it will work with this design maybe ill stick to media queries. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have element scroll able you should define width for it or it's parent .
so add min-width to your html style :

```
html {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   overflow-x: auto;
   min-width: 1000px;  # this is when html will be scroll-x
}
```